# Setting DataPoint for for Custom DataType in Google Fit

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm getting the following error when trying to set the datapoint for my custom datatype for my app that will use Google Fit.

Error: getValue (com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field) in DataPoint cannot be applied to (int)

```
DataPoint dataPoint = DataPOint.create(myDataSource);
dataPoint.getValue(0).setInt(totalCount);
dataSet.add(dataPoint);
```

I know I am missing something but i'm not sure what.

Comment: Ok so I realized I need to put the Field in getValue() but what am I supposed to enter when my data type has a custom field like: .addField("field1", Field.FORMAT_INT32)

Answer (score 3):

I had to create my own field, not sure what .zzn is but after exploring the Field datatype I saw this method and it seems to be working for far

```
myField = Field.zzn("custom",Field.FORMAT_INT32);
DataTypeCreateRequest request = new DataTypeCreateRequest.Builder()
        .setName("net.riversidestudios.pushupchallenge.pushup")
        .addField(myField)
        .build();
```

Comment: Seems like is now called `Field.zzo`. You have to look at the obfuscated source to find it. It's the first `public static` method in version 11.6.2. It's also worthwhile creating a `Contract` class to store these `Field` so you can reuse them