# How to set the value of a custom DataType Field in Google FIT API?

Tags: java, android, google-fit, custom-data-type, google-fit-api

I am trying to create a custom DataType similar to Google docs.

https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/custom

I can successfully create the DataType and a Field, yet not set it's value. Here is the code.

```
  public void writeCustomDatatype() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    // Write data to Fit
 Task<DataType> response = Fitness.getConfigClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
            .createCustomDataType(new DataTypeCreateRequest.Builder()
            .setName("com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.stepcounter.CustomDataGender1")
                    .addField("custom", Field.FORMAT_INT32)
                    .build());

    // Get data to Fit
             response = Fitness.getConfigClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
            .readDataType("com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.stepcounter.CustomDataGender1")
                     .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataType>() {
                         @Override
                         public void onSuccess(DataType dataType) {
                              dataTypeGender =  dataType;
                             updateGender();
                             Log.w(TAG, "Success in getting the gender" + dataType);
                         }
                     }).addOnFailureListener(
                             new OnFailureListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                     Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the gender.", e);
                                 }
                             });
}

// Updating Gender
private Task<Void> updateGender() {
    // Create a new dataset and update request.
    DataSet dataSet = updateGenderData();
    long startTime = 0;
    long endTime = 0;

    // Get the start and end times from the dataset.
    for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
        startTime = dataPoint.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        endTime = dataPoint.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    // [START update_data_request]
    Log.i(TAG, "Updating the Gender! - dataset in the History API.");

    DataUpdateRequest request =
            new DataUpdateRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataSet(dataSet)
                    .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();

    // Invoke the History API to update data.
    return Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .updateData(request)
            .addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // At this point the data has been updated and can be read.
                                Log.i(TAG, "Data update was successful for Gender.");
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "There was a problem updating the dataset.", task.getException());
                            }
                        }
                    });
}


// Update the Gender Data
private DataSet updateGenderData(){
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating a new data update request.");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Create a data source
    DataSource dataSource =
            new DataSource.Builder()
                    .setAppPackageName(this)
                    .setDataType(dataTypeGender)
                    .setStreamName(TAG + " - Gender")
                    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                    .build();

    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);

    DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    Value value = dataPoint.getValue(Field.custom(gender));
    dataPoint.getValue(Field.FORMAT_STRING).setString(gender);

    String test = value.toString();

    dataSet.add(dataPoint);
    // [END build_update_data_request]
    return dataSet;
}
```

These two lines both do not work. The first line the Field.custom does not exist so it's red in the IDE even if I created the Field and the corresponding DataType. In the second line dataPoint.getValue(), the getValue() Method wants a Field and no other Field really works right now.

```
Value value = dataPoint.getValue(Field.custom(gender));
dataPoint.getValue(Field.FORMAT_STRING).setString(gender);
```

I need a Field and I can't use a Field called custom even when I created a custom dataType Field called custom. This is from my debugger.

DataType{com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.stepcounter.CustomDataGender1[custom(i)]}.

I can't set the value of the custom data types when I use custom data types it works for pre-defined datatypes. Like TYPE.FIELD_WEIGHT or TYPE.FIELD_HEIGHT. Here is an example:

```
DataPoint dataPoint =
            dataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_HEIGHT).setFloat(heightDecimalMoved);
```

For example this does not work as a solution for me. I've tried multiple variants of setting up the custom Field like this they all do not work currently.
[Setting DataPoint for for Custom DataType in Google Fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637246/setting-datapoint-for-for-custom-datatype-in-google-fit)

Here is also how the custom datatype looks like that I generated with the code above. I used an integer as format that is why it say's (i).

DataType{com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.stepcounter.CustomDataGender1[custom(i)]}

The DataType for a pre-defined DataType by Google would look like this, this time with a String format.

DataType{com.google.weight[weight(f)]}

Any ideas what to do or how to proceed? I can create a custom Field with primitive datatypes for a custom DataType. But, I can't set the value similar to the pre-defined DataTypes from GoogleFit and the example I provided above, with the pre-defined DataTypes Weight and Height.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType

Comment: Third party apps are not allowed to create data types in the `com.google.*` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I can change the namespace of the package. I also found a solution.

Comment: How is it even possible to upload gender data and see the change in google fit itself? It works for height and weight.